# Missing class errors running Java built with Ant

Tags: java, ant

I have some code that I revised.

When I try to just run Ant in the directory it fails with missing classes. I can specify the location to the existing classes by using the -lib option to ant. The compile then works fine, however dist ZIP file that is created appears to have missing libraries, as when I try to run it, I see errors relating to missing classes which are the classes that I specified with the -lib option, so this is probably due to the way I have used the -lib option.

How can I force the regular Ant command to include the additional classes specified with the -lib command?

Answer (score 1):

You can write a target that will copy your lib directory/files in your zip file. 
Let's say create a temp dir then copy your files then execute target for copying lib directory and then zip temp dir.

```
<target name="copyLib">
    <copy todir="${temp.dir}">
         <fileset dir="${lib.dir}">
            <include name="*.jar" />                        
        </fileset>
    </copy>
</target>
```

Update paths and call this target into your create zip target.

Comment: Thanks, I know very little about ant. How would I actually do that? It sounds like what I need.

Answer (score 1):

Compiler task could look like this:

```
<javac srcdir="${base}/src" 
      destdir="${base}/classes" 
      classpath="${base}/lib">
</javac>
```

And the `zip` task could look like this:

```
<zip
    destfile="${base}/dist.jar"
    basedir="${base}/classes"
    includes="..."
    excludes="...">
</zip>
```

So sources are compiled in classes and zipped in a jar, but *libraries used for compile are not included in the jar*, they are runtime dependencies.

Comment: this assumes ${base}/lib has java classes, and is not a set of jars

Comment: According to ANT documentation https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/javac.html, `classpath` has a path-like structure, so it can perfectly be a folder with jars https://ant.apache.org/manual/using.html#path

Comment: you would need to specify a  <pathelement location="${base}/lib/somejar.jar"/> for each jar

Comment: `<classpath><fileset dir="lib"><include name="**/*.jar"/></fileset></classpath>` but `<javac classpath="${base}/lib"></javac>` works as well

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you declare your paths at the top of your ANT scripts as follows, using a fileset.

```
<path id="build.path">
    <fileset dir="lib" includes="*.jar"/>
</path>
```

Less error prone compared to forcing users to specify the correct "-lib" parameter.

Finally the same fileset can then be used to include the same jars inside the zip file you're creating:

```
  <zip destfile="${dist.dir}/mycode.zip">
    ..
    ..
    <fileset dir="lib" includes="*.jar"/>
  </zip>
```